# How to plan a "secure" HTML FORM

Tags: php, html, security, forms-authentication

I use $_POST to read data sent through HTML forms to the server, narrowing down attacks exposure.
How can I strengthen security, using some kind of tokens in the form? 
The tokens could be readable however with a sniffer.....

**** EDIT *****
I agree the message above is generic...I'll try to give more details!

Ok, a PHP/Server generates emails containing some data for a sort of user-revision; this is accomplished with an HTML email containing HTML forms. When users receive those emails, they edit data in the forms, and send it back to the server, that in turn it will store it in the database.

While for other types of interaction users/server, login/authentication is required, in this case some particular email clients, like mobile phones, do allow reading HTML email messages and process forms, unfortunately without allowing client authentication (server side login) prior processing the form.

What happens on the server side when forms are received? 
Well $_POST is used, removing potential GET weakness, however using $_POST will not prevent other kind of attacks, just because a sniffer can easily "read" data being sent.

Data on the server side is parsed and stripped accordingly, removing unsafe Javascript and quoted text to prevent injections and other sort of attacks.

That's why I was looking for a sort of token/nonce technique, however I thought that tokens are sniffable within the form..... and that's where my help request starts!

Comment: which attacks are you talking about? Secure in what sense?

Comment: Using $_POST does nothing whatsoever to narrow down attack exposure. It does, however, provide the user with a sense of security that their password isn't being shown in the URL bar.

Comment: Tokens can be used as a server side defense.  When the form is generated for the user, a one time token is provided.  It can only be submitted once and then the token is invalidated on the server side.  The attack vector of someone sniffing the entire form and being able to submit it before the original user is prettttty insignificant I would think, especially if the token is session/user specific.

Comment: Sorry guys I have edited the message adding more information for you!

Comment: Please go back and accept some answers for your questions by clicking the green check mark next to the correct answer.

Comment: @Shane the answers are quite generic (as the question was). Do i need to choose one although I have added more detials to my question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are probably refereing to CSRF (Cross site request forgery). [Chris Shiftlett wrote an article about it](http://shiflett.org/articles/cross-site-request-forgeries) which explains the concept.

Answer (score 3):

Here are a few things you should look into.

- SSL Certificates
- [CSRF Protection](http://www.codewalkers.com/c/a/Miscellaneous/Stopping-CSRF-Attacks-in-Your-PHP-Applications/)

Answer (score -1):

Ok, I have discovered that Wordpress offers it's own API for NONCES.
What I do now is to add an input field in the form containg the NONCE; when user sends form to the server, the NONCE is validate back.

There's a little chance an attacker could gain access using NONCE contained in the form ** ONLY ** during the lap time occurring between NONCE issue/verify. Quite difficult though: the attacker should sniff data, grab the NONCE and use it immediately to load "something" in the database...
What could it be loaded, assuming content is being stripslashed and de-javascripted?

Moreover, as WP NONCES are created using constants:

```
wp_create_nonce  ('my-nonce');
```

this will require some additional tasks to use variable generated NONCES in such a way for the attacker it will be more difficult to track the pattern to generate the NONCE...

What do you think?